# How can I read JSON from URL, output FLOAT to app screen? SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I`m new at swift and need to read json file from url. I managed to get the data and output it to the aplication screen(when it is String), but how can I correct convert it from float and output to the app screen?

```
import SwiftUI

struct DATA: Codable {
    let ONE_R: Float
    let TWO_R: Float
}

struct AllTEC: View {
    @State var user: DATA?
    var body: some View {
        Text("ONE: \(user?.ONE_R ?? "")")  \\correct for string incorrect for float
            .onAppear(perform: loadD)
    }
}

extension AllTEC
{
    func loadD() {

    let url = URL(string: "https://symbiosys-a415a.firebaseio.com/DATA.json")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
              print("error: \(error!)")
              return
        }
        guard let data = data else{
              print("no data")
              return
        }
        guard let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(DATA.self, from: data) else {
        print("Error: Couldn't decode data ito user")
        return
        }
        print("gotten user is \(user.ONE_R)")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.user = user
    }
    task.resume()
   }
}

struct AllTEC_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
          AllTEC()
    }
}
```

JSON

```
{
"ONE_R":98.4,
"TWO_R":27.7
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Simply use float value for nil coalescing

Replace:

```
Text("ONE: \(user?.ONE_R ?? "")")
```

With:

```
Text("ONE: \(user?.ONE_R ?? 0)")
```

**Previous:** Update the model to accept `Float` as parameters.

```
struct DATA: Codable {
    let ONE_R: Float
    let TWO_R: Float
}
```

Comment: Check this article https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-specify-floating-point-precision-in-a-string